# Sum if date exists for this month

Tags: sql, sum, int, case, converters

I'am trying to work out the AmountRequested for all completed cases for this month.
I'am using SQL 2008

If there is a date in the column DateCompleted for this month then give me the sum of AmountRequested for those columns 
Here is my code it keeps falling over saying "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"

```
SUM(case WHEN CONVERT(DATE,pm.DateCompleted,103) 
 = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(pm.DateCompleted) = YEAR(GETDATE())
   THEN pm.AmountRequested 
       ELSE 0 end) AS [LoanAmount]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CONVERT(DATE,pm.DateCompleted,103) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Here you are trying to compare `date` with `integer` so the error.

**Ex.** 
`CONVERT(DATE,pm.DateCompleted,103)` may return `'2016-10-11'` and `MONTH(GETDATE())` will return `10`. You trying to equate `'2016-10-11' = 10` so the error is generated

Why not use the same `MONTH` function for your column also

```
Sum(CASE
        WHEN Month(pm.DateCompleted) = Month(Getdate())
            AND Year(pm.DateCompleted) = Year(Getdate()) THEN pm.AmountRequested
        ELSE 0
    END) AS [LoanAmount]
```

Comment: Perfect thanks Prdp So the convert was causing the issue.

Comment: @RustyHamster Yeah you are trying to compare `date` with `integer` that is the real problem. Ex. `CONVERT(DATE,pm.DateCompleted,103)` may return `'2016-10-11'` and `MONTH(GETDATE())` will return `10` You trying to equate `'2016-10-11' = 10` so the error is generated

Comment: Thanks for explaining it makes sense much appreciated.